# How to open a file with an editor via terminal

Tags: python, macos, operating-system

The goal is: opening a .py file with an IDE(ex.VS Code) with using terminal, and using the code in python os.

```
os.system("python3 test.py")
```

but this code RUNS the file, I want to open it with an editor.

Comment: So replace `python3` with your favorite editor executable?

Answer (score 1):

Most editors lets you open files by putting the name of the editor behind the file. For example, in a terminal, you can write `code` to open VSCode

```
code test.py
```

So with the os lib, you could use

```
os.system("code test.py")
```

Comment: sh: code: command not found

Comment: @acsolak34 which os you are using?

Comment: I use macOS....

Comment: @acsolak34 check my answer if it works for you.

Comment: @acsolak34  once you try this let me know if this is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

```
os.system("vi test.py")
```

OR

```
os.system("cat test.py")
```

OR

```
os.system("vim test.py")
```

OR

```
os.system("nano test.py")
```

Comment: @acsolak34 Check this if it works for you.

Comment: shows the codes in the terminal, doesn't open an IDE

Comment: @acsolak34 try nano or vim

Comment: vim I same with the above, nano didn't work at all